# how to correct forward neck posture?

Tags: strength, muscle, pain, muscle-recovery, neck

I am "**software programmer**". I recently noticed that i am victim of forward neck posture. I know my computer realated job is reason for this. I am trying to correct my posture. but while doing this i feeling more pain in neck and behind neck muscle. Please help me

Comment: Did you go see a specialist about this? This doesn't sound like something I would try to solve myself, especially if you're experiencing pain.

Comment: yes orthopedic doctor gave me some exercise to do. and i have been doing these since one month. but he is saying you have to correct your posture

Comment: Did the orthopedician suggest you a physiotherapist? My simple advice is to role a small towel and place under your neck while you sleep. I am also a developer and I do this to solve the neck problem

Comment: I would also check out Anterior Pelvic tilt. This is also a common problems for those who are in the software industry.

Comment: I started doing burpees and see results after one day. This is despite various stretching exercises for psoas and etc. in the past. I can't say if this applies to you, but I am kind of blown away by the effectiveness of these things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Forward head posture (called [gravity induced kyphosis](http://www.exrx.net/ExInfo/Posture.html)) is pretty common nowadays.  The first thing you should do is begin stretching your neck with an exercise called [neck retraction](http://www.exrx.net/Stretches/Sternocleidomastoid/NeckRetraction.html):

[image]

You'll be amazed at how great this exercise feels.  If you've been stuck in forward head posture for a long time, you'll feel as though your entire upper spine is waking up.

Once you've developed some "normal" flexibility in your neck, you can start to strengthen the muscles so that they are more balanced.  This will help keep your head upright.  The exercises you'll want to incorporate to your workout routine are:

[Cervical flexion](http://www.exrx.net/Articulations/Spine.html#anchor160581):

[image]

[Cervical extension](http://www.exrx.net/Articulations/Spine.html#anchor161500):

[image]

[Lateral cervical flexion](http://www.exrx.net/Articulations/Spine.html#anchor162283):

[image]

If you don't have a machine, you can use free weights to perform these exercises.  For instance, a [neck harness](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Splenius/WtNeckHarnessExt.html) may be used:

[image]

If you do not have a neck harness, plates or dumbbells may be used [like so](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Sternocleidomastoid/WtNeckFlx.html):

[image]

Check out the [neck exercise index](http://www.exrx.net/Lists/ExList/NeckWt.html) on [exrx](http://www.exrx.net/) for some other ideas.  I also found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHuB1jKY59g) video to be worth watching.

In addition to these neck exercises, you should consider adding some [deadlifts](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/ErectorSpinae/BBDeadlift.html) to your routine to balance the muscles of the upper back.

Answer (score 1):

To correct your posture will take time; however, it's a possible and easy thing to do.

#### Equipment needed

- A full length mirror or reflective surface
- A chair

#### Procedure

1. Google "proper standing posture" and "proper sitting posture" and download some of the images
2. Stand in front of the mirror, mimicking the proper posture in the "proper standing posture" images
3. Practise the posture a few times in front of the mirror.
4. Practise the posture a few times without the mirror.
5. Practise Steps 2 - 4 using the "proper sitting posture" images
6. Take the images with you wherever you go, trying as best as possible to mimick the positions.
7. Within a few days, you'll begin to get a hang of it.

Most likely, you'll begin to feel some pain in your back after a while. This is due to weak lower back muscles. You need strong back muscles for a good posture. To strengthen your back muscles, perform

- pull ups or chin ups.
- Planks *(also called bridge)*
- knee ups too *(if you can)*.

You also need to practise frequent walking in good posture. Your back muscles will strengthen after a while. 
 
You might need to re-adjust your work chair/desk to match the proper posture. 
 
Sit straight at work; ***do not slouch.*** 
 
All these will correct your posture and any current pain you experience will be gone in a relatively short time. 
 
Now, go download those pictures :).